# C# check if datetime value in MySql database is today

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I am currently trying to get all the appointments for a user out of the database based on the date they clicked on a calendar.

When clicked on the calendar a variable will get the value of eg. 
20-06-2016 00:00:00

Now I want to return every appointment location of today using this date.
I use this query: 
`SELECT appo_location WHERE id = 'variable_id' AND date ='variable_date';`

This is not really working. When i execute it says I have an error in my SQL statement.  Also will my code get every appointment that is today when i use this: 20-06-2016 00:00:00 ? because it's only the start of the day.

This is my actual query:

```
query = "SELECT afspraak_locatie WHERE id = '" + item + "' AND datum = '" + datum +"'";
```

Comment: I think you should add your actual code and not a template of it. The syntax error could be explained easily seeing your code.

Comment: Where is your table name?

Comment: @BonMacalindong omg you are right

Comment: @Kason i think you misspelled `From` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all data within the date, then you should compare only the date (excluding the time). You can use the `DATE` function.

```
"SELECT afspraak_locatie FROM your_table_name
WHERE id = '" + item  + "' AND DATE(datum) = DATE('" + your_date_variable + "')"
```

Comment: `[]` is not valid syntax for MySQL, use backticks instead.

Comment: Well no need to use back ticks since datum is not a mysql identifier. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 2):

`date` should be `[date]`. `date` is keyword so you should use `[date]` for your `column name` in query. Hope it works!

**EDIT**

Your query is wrong. `SELECT` (columns) `FROM` (table). Where is `FROM` keyword?

Comment: I use the dutch word for date "datum". I don't think it is a reserved word.

Comment: Your query is wrong. SELECT (columns) FROM (table). Where is `FROM`?

Comment: `[]` is not valid syntax for MySQL, use backticks instead.

Comment: Thanks for knowledge. Glad to here your problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

**Create Table**

```
CREATE TABLE A
    (`id` int, `afspraak_locatie` varchar(1), `date` DATETIME)
;

INSERT INTO A
    (`id`,`afspraak_locatie`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1, 'A', '2016-06-20 14:30:00'),
    (1, 'B', '2016-06-20 15:30:00'),
    (1, 'C', '2016-06-20 16:30:00'),
    (1, 'D', '2016-06-20 17:30:00'),
    (2, 'E', '2016-06-20 15:30:00'),
    (2, 'F', '2016-06-20 14:30:00'),
    (2, 'G', '2016-06-20 13:30:00')
;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT afspraak_locatie
FROM A
WHERE id='1' AND DATE(date) = Date('2016-06-20 00:00:00')
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d3785/3)